# Creating ICS file in PHP only works on android?

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios, icalendar

My PHP code to create an ICS file works fine on android but doesn't work on my iPhone 12 (IOS 15.5). In android, the ics file is downloaded correctly, but on my iPhone, it doesn't do anything at all.
I already tried changing "METHOD:REQUEST" to "METHOD:PUBLISH" without success.
Anyone got an idea what I am doing wrong here ?

Here is my PHP code:

```
    header("Content-Type: text/Calendar; charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=ADL_kalender.ics");
    echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
    echo "VERSION:2.0\n";
    echo "PRODID:-//www.website.be//\n";
    echo "METHOD:REQUEST\n"; // required by Outlook
    echo "ORGANIZER:TEST\n";  // nodig voor Outlook ?
    
        //   Loop through array (= result of query)
        foreach ($result_array as $ontmoeting) {
            $speelweek = $ontmoeting['Ontmoeting_Speelweek'];
            $thuisploeg = $ontmoeting['Ploegnaam_Thuis'];
            $uitploeg = $ontmoeting['Ploegnaam_Uit'];

            $jaar = substr($ontmoeting['Ontmoeting_Datum'],0,4);
            $maand = substr($ontmoeting['Ontmoeting_Datum'],5,2);
            $dag = substr($ontmoeting['Ontmoeting_Datum'],8,2);
            $uur = substr($ontmoeting['Speeluur_Thuis'],0,2) . substr($ontmoeting['Speeluur_Thuis'],3,2);
            
            $start = $jaar . $maand . $dag . 'T' . $uur . '00';
            if ($uur === '1330') {
                $end = $jaar . $maand . $dag . 'T' . '173000';
            } elseif ($uur === '1915') {
                $end = $jaar . $maand . $dag . 'T' . '230000';
            }
             
            $location = $ontmoeting['Lokaal_Thuis'] . " - " . $ontmoeting['Lokaal_Straat_Thuis'] . " - " . $ontmoeting['Lokaal_Postcode_Thuis'] . " " . $ontmoeting['Lokaal_Gemeente_Thuis'];
            $name = 'ADL : ' . $thuisploeg. ' - ' . $uitploeg;
            $description = 'Wedstrijd ID : ' . $ontmoeting['Ontmoeting_ID'] . '. Speelweek : ' . $speelweek;
            $slug = 'wedstrijd_id_' . $ontmoeting['Ontmoeting_ID'];

            echo "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
            echo "UID:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand()."ADL2000\n"; // required by Outlook
            echo "UID:". $slug . "\n"; // required by Outlook
            echo "STATUS:CONFIRMED\n";
            echo "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."\n"; // required by Outlook
            echo "DTSTART:{$start}\n"; 
            echo "DTEND:{$end}\n";
            echo "LOCATION:{$location}\n";
            echo "SUMMARY:{$name}\n";
            echo "DESCRIPTION: {$description}\n";
            echo "END:VEVENT\n";
        }    

    echo "END:VCALENDAR\n";
```

And this is the JS code that calls he PHP script and opens the ICS file :

```
function HTMLtoICS() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        async: false,
        url:'includes/Get_kalender_ICS.inc.php',
        data: {lokaal_id:lokaal_id, ploeg_id:ploeg_id, optie1:optie1, optie2:optie2},
        success: function(response){
            var icsMSG = response;
            window.open( "data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't help you with your problem, but I can hopefully simplify things to help debugging. Right now you've got PHP, HTTP (transport), HTML (host), JavaScript, jQuery and AJAX. We can remove a bunch of these and test JS only by being literal (while debugging): https://gist.github.com/cjhaas/43c3b6d4fb31c68f5f3cea0739d90ca0. If that works on Android but still not iOS, it is probably a MIME or ICS-specific problem that hopefully someone can help pinpoint.

Comment: `window.open( "data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG));` - is `escape` really the correct method to use here, I wonder? Apart from that it is semi-deprecated, I think `encodeURIComponent` would make more sense here.

Comment: @Chris Haas : I use PHP to run a query to get the info for the ICS file. Anyway, I made the ICS file now in JS as you suggested. This is (a short version of) the ICS file I get :

Comment: "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//www.adl2000.be//
METHOD:REQUEST
ORGANIZER:TEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:20220811T142844-123232ADL2000
UID:5027
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTAMP:20220811T142844
DTSTART:20220908T191500
DTEND:20220908T230000
LOCATION:Café Den Bonten Os - Kerkstraat 6 - 2560 Nijlen
SUMMARY:ADL : BC Den Bonten Os - BC De Living
DESCRIPTION:Wedstrijd ID : 5027. Speelweek : 1
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
"

Comment: Still doesn't function on the iPhone...

Comment: Update: I finally found the solution. I had to declare the icsMSG as a global variable to be able to open it outside the loop where I gathered the data for the icsMSP file. Strange, because that wasn't necessary the previous year. So, quite silly from my side, but still strange that it worked on android but not on my iPhone...